# AngularJS not waiting for HTTP request to be done

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

Hello guys I have the following code here :

```
angular.module('todomvc')
.factory('todoStorage', function ($http) {
    'use strict';

    var STORAGE_ID = 'todos-angularjs';

    return {
        get: function () {
            $http({method: 'GET', url: '/api/todo.php'}).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              // this callback will be called asynchronously
              // when the response is available
              return JSON.stringify(data);
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              // called asynchronously if an error occurs
              // or server returns response with an error status.
            });
        },

        put: function (todos) {
            debugger;
            localStorage.setItem(STORAGE_ID, JSON.stringify(todos));
        }
    };
});
```

as well as

```
angular.module('todomvc')
.controller('TodoCtrl', function TodoCtrl($scope, $routeParams, $filter, todoStorage, $http) {
    'use strict';

    var todos = $scope.todos = todoStorage.get();

    $scope.newTodo = '';
    $scope.editedTodo = null;

    $scope.$watch('todos', function (newValue, oldValue) {
        $scope.remainingCount = $filter('filter')(todos, { completed: false }).length;
        $scope.completedCount = todos.length - $scope.remainingCount;
        $scope.allChecked = !$scope.remainingCount;
        if (newValue !== oldValue) { // This prevents unneeded calls to the local storage
            todoStorage.put(todos);
        }
    }, true);
```

The issue i have is that the HTTP request is not completing before the code at $scope.$watch is being executed therefore it is calling .length on undefined. I am a total n00b to Angular and wanted to use this TodoMVC to get it working however im not sure what i can do to halt the whole process instead of wrapping the rest of the code within the success callback from the http request.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The whole code is over @ http://pastebin.com/5vkpHyUU

Comment: Are you using `ngRoute`? Then you could use the resolve feature.

Comment: @user3621357 Any luck with any of the answers yet?

Answer (score 2):

Issue

- #1 you need to return promise from your `get` method of your factory, and use `$http.then` instead of http's custom promise method `success`.
- #2 you need to chain it though to assign value to the scope property.
- #3 when you watch asyncronously assigned properties you need to have a null check because the watch is going to run when the controller is set up.
- #4 I am not sure if you should do JSON.stringify the response because looks like you are in need of an array data?

In your factory

```
 return {
    get: function () {
      return  $http({method: 'GET', url: '/api/todo.php'}). //Return here
        then(function(response) { //
            return response.data;
        }, function(response) {
          // called asynchronously if an error occurs
          // or server returns response with an error status.
        });
    },
```

In your controller:-

```
   var todos;
   todoStorage.get().then(function(data) {
       todos = $scope.todos = data
   });
```

and

```
   $scope.$watch('todos', function (newValue, oldValue) {
       if(!newValue) return;
        $scope.remainingCount = $filter('filter')(todos, { completed: false }).length;
        $scope.completedCount = todos.length - $scope.remainingCount;
        $scope.allChecked = !$scope.remainingCount;
        if (newValue !== oldValue) { // This prevents unneeded calls to the local storage
            todoStorage.put(todos);
        }
    }, true);
```

Comment: So i would return a promise from the factory and once that is done then the rest of the code would run in the main controller?

Comment: @user3621357 See my answer, i have mentioned the code snippet, btw why are you doing a JSON.stringify of the response.

Comment: I wasnt sure what a better way to do this was? On the API?

Answer (score 0):

`$http` is wrapped in a promise. You could return the promise from the service:

```
return $http({method: 'GET', url: '/api/todo.php'})
```

In the controller you can use `then` method to specify the behaviour when the request is completed:

```
 $scope.newTodo = '';
 $scope.editedTodo = null;

todoStorage.get().then(function(result) {

    $scope.todos = result.data;

    $scope.$watch('todos', function (newValue, oldValue) {
        $scope.remainingCount = $filter('filter')($scope.todos, { completed: false }).length;
        $scope.completedCount = todos.length - $scope.remainingCount;
        $scope.allChecked = !$scope.remainingCount;
        if (newValue !== oldValue) { // This prevents unneeded calls to the local storage
            todoStorage.put($scope.todos);
        }
    }, true);
 });
```

A good example about how to chain promises:

http://codepen.io/willh/pen/fCtuw

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
angular.module('todomvc')
    .factory('todoStorage', function ($http) {
        'use strict';

    var STORAGE_ID = 'todos-angularjs';

    return {
        get: function () {
            return $http({method: 'GET', url: '/api/todo.php'})
        },

        put: function (todos) {
            debugger;
            localStorage.setItem(STORAGE_ID, JSON.stringify(todos));
        }
    };
});


angular.module('todomvc')
.controller('TodoCtrl', function TodoCtrl($scope, $routeParams, $filter, todoStorage, $http) {
    'use strict';

    $scope.newTodo = '';
    $scope.editedTodo = null;
     todoStorage.get()
         .then(function(d){
          $scope.todos=d;
     })
         .catch(function(e){
          console.error(e);
      })

    $scope.$watch('todos', function (newValue, oldValue) {
        $scope.remainingCount = $filter('filter')(todos, { completed: false }).length;
        $scope.completedCount = todos.length - $scope.remainingCount;
        $scope.allChecked = !$scope.remainingCount;
        if (newValue !== oldValue) { // This prevents unneeded calls to the local storage
            todoStorage.put(todos);
        }
    }, true);
```